# react native webview doesn't open external broswer on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, plaid

I used react-native-webview(version 11.23.0) for Plaid OAuth.
The webview page show Plaid OAuth page. When I tap a bank from the list, it will redirect to sign in page of the bank.
On Android, it opens external browser, but iOS doesn't open an external browser.
How can I fix this issue on iOS?
Please help me.

I need to open an external browser when tap a button in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Plaid React Native SDK as well? Note that using a webview-based integration without one of Plaid's mobile SDKs (React Native, iOS, or Android) is discouraged due to the behavior of webviews + OAuth.

If you are not using the React Native SDK, make sure you have the following code in your iOS integration:

https://github.com/plaid/plaid-link-examples/blob/master/webviews/wkwebview/wkwebview/LinkViewController.swift#L56-L72

```
    func webView(
        _ webView: WKWebView,
        createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
        for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
        windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures
    ) -> WKWebView? {
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            return nil
        }

        // Open the external URL in Safari
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: I used Plaid in webview. 

import sdk from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/bond-sdk-web';

Comment: The Bond SDK isn't something we officially support, so it's not something I know much about and I'm not sure whether you can achieve what you're looking to with it. However, feel free to submit a Plaid support ticket if you need further help.